# How do I make PHP files work with Amazon hosting?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting

I have a website that I'm helping a friend upload to Amazon to host.  All of the web files are html integrated with PHP so that one PHP file might represent the header, one may represent the body, and one may represent the footer.

Normally I would just upload it to my HostGator account and life would be good, but I guess I can't just put it in a bucket and have it work in Amazon S3.

How do I set it up so that my PHP files work?

I realize that I can't solely use S3. So do I put some files on S3, or does everything go on EC2? And how to I get EC2 working? I just have some .php files I need to work. Are there any official tutorials that will help me set up EC2 to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/). You simply upload your application, and Elastic Beanstalk automatically handles the deployment details of capacity provisioning, load balancing, auto-scaling, and application health monitoring. Here is a link to the [PHP Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html). Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, setting up a PHP app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (with simplified deployment options) is substantially simpler than trying to configure an EC2 instance by itself. Elastic Beanstalk now supports single-instance environments, so it's essentially a single EC2 machine with Git deployments.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3, being the *Simple* Storage Service, doesn't handle anything dynamic like PHP.

PHP hosting on Amazon involves setting up EC2 instances, which is just like managing any other server or VPS.

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to help. Maybe you could look at my edit and offer a little guidance?

Comment: PHP files are useless on S3. You can store stuff like images, downloadable files, etc. there if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon s3 is only for maintaining your files. For hosting your files you have to look into another amazon service **amazon ec2**.

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to help. Maybe you could look at my edit and offer a little guidance?

Comment: Refer the following link http://www.robotmedia.net/2011/04/how-to-create-an-amazon-ec2-instance-with-apache-php-and-mysql-lamp/

Answer (score 0):

S3 is a just an object storage service. Its a good place to put static files like images/css/javascript which you can serve directly without putting more load on your ec2 instance(s)

EC2 is more or less a virtual machine running the OS you choose. You can configure it to run just about anything. This is where your php application would be hosted.

If you don't understand how to take advantage of both, just stick to EC2 until you have a better understanding of how to use each system. You can configure your ec2 instance with a basic LAMP stack and treat it like you would your traditional hosting.

Answer (score 0):

i am using Elastic Beanstalk, for ruing my php based API application. its very easy to mange and run php files.

Open you console https://console.aws.amazon.com
and find **Elastic Beanstalk**

here select new Environment for php and deploy and after all upload php application by zip file. and after uploading you can see a path/URL to see you index file.